# Graph Expansion

Tags: language-agnostic, graph

I'm currently working on an interesting graph problem, I can't find any algorithms or other stackoverflow questions which mention anything like this.

**If I have a graph (undirected, cyclic) and a list of commonly used paths, what is the best way to reduce the average path length by adding in N more edges?**

EDIT:: Important point, which might help, all paths start at the same node.

Comment: Can it be assumed that the commonly used paths are each equally important?

Comment: The paths can be ordered by number of uses, so the best thing to do is order them by usage.

Comment: The graph is actually a peer to peer network, so in this case paths could actually be ordered by amount of data sent, or latency, depending on what I want to minimise. Basically assume the paths can be ordered in importance somehow quite simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution, which sounds like it might be the best heuristic, is to take the weighted average of all the end nodes (weighted by path importance), then find the node which is closest to the computed average point. Connect to that node.

Obviously that only works if the nodes are laid out in space somehow, but it's a good analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, to cover what I've already considered.

The obvious solution is simply to sort the common paths by order, and slot in a connection between the two ends, and keep doing this until you run out of edges to insert. However, I suspect there is a more intelligent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try inserting all possible edges and see how much the shortest path decreases for each of your given start/end points.  Pick the best edge and repeat.

The usefulness of edges depends on what other edges have been added, so if you really want optimality, you'd have to try all sets of N edges.  That sounds a tad expensive.  Wouldn't surprise me if it was NP-hard.

Interesting question!

Comment: Hmm, that's a fairly obvious solution, why didn't I think of that? xD

As you say, that's probably going to have some very nasty performance characteristics! Some kind of heuristic algorithm is going to be needed to cut it down.

Comment: since Dijkstras algorithm is O(E + VlogV)

We have (N-1)! pairs of nodes (rhoughly), which means (V-1)!-E pairs which are not already linked. Since we need to do a pathfind for every path (call that number P), performance would be

P * O((E+1) + VlogV) * ((V-1)! - E)

I believe, which is pretty much dominated by that factorial. It's a generally pretty godawful characteristic :/